# Return a list of procedures that where the function at position k adds k to the input without using cons or list function in scheme?

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I want a function that returns a list of functions  where functions at position k returns the input plus k.

example

(define myfunc ( the-required-function 5 ) )

((car myfunc ) 1) = 2

((cadr myfunc ) 1) = 3

((caddr myfunc ) 1) = 4

etc.

This has to be accomplished using cons and letrec and simple conditional only?

Use of append or external functions are not allowed.

Te only functions allowed are lambdas,cons,conditional are the only ones allowed. Okay to define and call a lambda though.

Any ideas on how to achieve this.

```
( define (gen-fn-list n)
    (letrec ((fn (lambda (k n) (if (= k n) (cons (lambda (x) (+ x k)) '() )
    (cons (lambda (x)(+ x k) ) (fn (+ k 1) n) ) )))) (fn 1 n)))
```

I don't see how else can this be done. I believe I am not able to relate to a major idea of scheme or in usage of letrec's in scheme.

I am looking get the concept rather than a solution/code to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have written looks correct and reasonable to me. What are you hoping to get out of an answer to this question? An explanation of why this code (perhaps written by someone else) works? Suggestions of better ways to write it?

Comment: I am looking for a better (by which I mean a more intuitive) way of solving this problem.

I am just wondering if I have actually missed a nitty gritty in the understanding of recusion or power of scheme and solved in a more "it just happened to work" way.

That perspective is what I am looking for.

Comment: Given the limitations (just lambda, letrec, cons, and if), this looks pretty good to me. I would make a couple minor stylistic changes, most importantly insert several more newlines so nobody has to do manual paren-counting to figure out what goes where. But if you're looking for code review, try codereview.stackexchange.com.